# how to make default functions inside model in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

i want to make custom functions in models --

My Controller --

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class AdminsController extends AppController
{
    public function planSessions()
    {
        $this->loadmodel('Plans_sessions');
        $sessions = $this->Plans_sessions->getPlanSessions();
        $this->set('sessions',$sessions);
    }
}
```

My Model --

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class Plans_sessionsTable extends Table
{
    public function getPlanSessions()
    {
        return $this->query("select * from `plans_sessions` where category LIKE '%shop%' ");
    }
}
```

but it`s getting error -- Unknown method "getPlanSessions"

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the naming conventions:

```
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions
```

Table class names are plural and CamelCased. People, BigPeople, and ReallyBigPeople are all examples of conventional model names.

```
$this->PlansSessions->getPlanSessions();
```